# How to make one switch control multiple identical subcircuits?

Tags: switching

I have an audio circuit with 8 identical subcircuits (one for each voice).
In each subcircuit or voice, a resistor controls one aspect of the sound.
I would like to have a switch which allows me to switch between two different resistor values in that part of the circuit, thus altering the sound.

However I would like this single switch to make the same change simultaneously in all 8 subcircuits. What approach would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What approach would you recommend?*

A likely candidate is an analogue switch. You can get multiple independent analogue switches in one IC package and each can be "switched" on or off independently or together. They are also called transmission gates and when several are used together to form a multi-pole switch it is called an analogue multiplexer/demultiplexer.

You can get ICs that contain several (as already mentioned) and you some ICs have normally closed and normally open types in the same package. You can choose the on resistance to be from around 1 ohm to several hundred ohm and the off-state leakage current can be a few nano amps.

Usually, the control lines that are used to switch them on or off are digital voltage referenced making life easy if you want to control it from a microprocessor. Switching speed can be many MHz (if you need it).

One constraint - it has to be capable of running from the same power supplies as your circuit and the analogue voltages that are used have to be within those power rails.

Comment: Thanks for this Andy, this looks like the info I needed. I will explore this but as I'm unfamiliar with these ICs, do you have an idea of the configuration that would be required for my scenario - for example in this list of multiplexers, there are options for number of channels and configuration: https://www.mouser.co.uk/Semiconductors/Switch-ICs/Multiplexer-Switch-ICs/_/N-7590d

Comment: I have no technical insight into your circuit whatsoever. The devil is always in the detail.

Comment: If I have my terminology correct, the switch in each subcircuit is SPDT, as the option is between two paths through the circuit, each with a different resistor value. So to implement this 8 times, it looks like 2 of these 4 x SPDT ICs would work: https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/SN3257QDYYRQ1?qs=%252B6g0mu59x7JBBtJ8CeVEsA%3D%3D

I'll accept your answer, and any further recommendations on the specifics from anyone would be appreciated.

Comment: @Lemmy a SPST switch would be enough to add a parallel resistor to a circuit

Comment: @jsotola I am new to laying out circuits - but if using an SPST switch would you just put it next to the lower value resistor, in parallel with the higher value resistor? So current flows through high value resistor when switch is open, but diverts to go through low value resistor when switch is closed and the current has possibility of flowing through either?

Comment: in parallel resistors, the current flows through both, not just one .... adding a resistor in parallel, lowers the resistance

Comment: Of course... thanks.